# Parsing a time with the format HHMMSS00

Tags: go, time, sage-erp

I'm working with some data from multiple sources and one of these sources is a Sage ERP system.

I am trying to reference two files in Sage in particular, an audit date and audit time (`AUDTDATE` and `AUDTTIME`).

I need to parse this and store it as a DATETIME in a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Currently, I am just trying to figure out the best way to parse this.

An example of what the data might look like is below:

```
+----------+----------+
| AUDTDATE | AUDTTIME |
+----------+----------+
| 20170228 |  5013756 |
+----------+----------+
```

`AUDTDATE` is a yyyymmdd format and the `AUDTTIME` is HHMMSS00.

So I tried the below as a test:

```
func main() {
    value := "20170228 5013756"
    layout := "20060102 15040500"

    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, value)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

This doesn't work, it just returns `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` when run.

If I change the time to this `050137` and the layout to `150405` then this works fine:

```
func main() {
    value := "20170228 050137"
    layout := "20060102 150405"

    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, value)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

One way that I can think of to deal with this is to strip the milliseconds off from the end and then check the length and add a zero to the beginning if it needs one.

This seems like a pretty ugly solution and would involve doing something like this:

```
func main() {
    date := "20170228"
    timeString := "5013756"
    value := date + prepareTime(timeString)
    layout := "20060102150405"

    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, value)
    fmt.Println(t)
}

func prepareTime(time string) string {
    if len(time) == 7 {
        time = "0" + time
    }
    return time[:6]
}
```

**Is there a way to do this without going through the above? Perhaps natively with the time package?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're pulling back 2 separate values from the DB, you can use `fmt.Sprintf` to `0` pad `timeString`. Combining it with the `date` string, you can use the following:

```
value := fmt.Sprintf("%s %08s", date, timeString)[:15]
```

In your code:

```
func main() {
    date := "20170228"
    timeString := "5013756"
    value := fmt.Sprintf("%s %08s", date, timeString)[:15]
    layout := "20060102 150405"

    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, value)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Results:

```
2017-02-28 05:01:37 +0000 UTC
```

This approach is useful because it will also correctly pad any shorter value of time, e.g. `13756` will be converted to `00013756`.

The `fmt.Sprintf` function is useful to format arguments into a string using the formatting you desire as specified by a format string and a list of arguments (`...interface{}`). The format string tells the function how to render the arguments.

This format string uses two items of note:

- String verb (`%s`): The format string uses a variety of `verbs` that are used for string substitutions. `%s` is specifically to render a string or a slice. Other popular verbs include `%d` for base 10 integer and `%f` for float with a complete list in the docs. The `%v` verb is very useful can also be used here as it will render an argument's default value.
- `0` left padding: To `0` left pad an argument, use `0` followed by a length number in the verb after the `%`. This will prepended the argument with a maximum number of `0`s specified in the length number. For example, `%08s` will render a string with up to 8 prepended zeros. This means a string `""` will be `"00000000"` while a string `"1234567"` will result in `"01234567"`. If the string is longer than the length, nothing will be prepended.

From the documentation:

```
%s  the uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice

0   pad with leading zeros rather than spaces;
    for numbers, this moves the padding after the sign
```

More detailed is available in the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Comment: This looks like a much more elegant solution. `fmt.Sprintf("%s %08s", date, timeString)` would you mind explaining this a little more - I'm just trying to understand this a little more `"%s %08s"`. I am assuming the `%s` outputs the date as it is passed in and the `%08s` outputs the time as it is passed in with leading zeros upto 8 characters in length. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. I've updated the answer to include more of an explanation. As mentioned, this is useful here because it will result in the correct time length, even if more than one `0` is needed. The `%s` and `%08s` both indicate the values are strings, with `%08s` indicating to prepend a string with up to 8 zeroes. In this particular instance, `"%v %08v"` can also be used because `%v` indicates to use a default value of the argument. `%v` can be used for any struct but it's nice to be more specific when you can, `%s` here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Very useful. I'm quite new to Go and this is very helpful.